# How can I make this code shorter? Is it possible to create this in one loop?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var rw = 50;
var rh = 50;
var x = 10;
var y = 10;

for (x=10, y=10; y<240; x=x+60, y=y+57) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
}
  for (x=10, y=67; y<240; x=x+60, y=y+57) {
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
}

  for (x=10, y=124; y<240; x=x+60, y=y+57) {
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
}

  for (x=10, y=181; y<240; x=x+60, y=y+57) {
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
}

  for (x=10, y=238; y<240; x=x+60, y=y+57) {
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
}
```

It's a javascript code. In my html is this

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

My task is, come this code together below one loop.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: <canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas> /my html/

Comment: sounds more like a [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this shorthand with a function. In your code just the `y` part is changing the rest is the same. So you can create a function and pass `y` as a parameter into it.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function fillRect(y, rw = 50, rh = 50) {
   for(var x = 10; y < 240; x += 60, y += 57) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
      ctx.fillRect(x,y,rw,rh);
   }
}

for (const y of [10, 67, 124, 181, 238]) {
    fillRect(y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: And then use `for (const y of [10, 67, 124, 184, 238]) fillRect(y)` (and then  possibly inline the function there). But agreed: creating a function should always be the first thought

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you can do following:

- Create a nested loop and set initial value of `y` based on iteration.
- Create a variable for increment factor and use it across. This will make it easy to change in future.
- Though this is minor, you can move declaration of `x` and `y` to for loop, since you are initializing it in every for loop. This will be useful if you switch to ES6 in future.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var rw = 50;
var rh = 50;
var xFactor = 60;
var yFactor = 57;
var noOfItems = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < noOfItems; i++) {
  for (var x = 10, y = 10 + (i * yFactor); y < 240; x += xFactor, y += yFactor) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, rw, rh);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be shorter. But looks like a nested loop is required as :

```
for(row=0;row<5;row++) {
  for(col=0;col < row+1; col++)  {
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(x + col * 60 ,y + row * 57,rw,rh);
  }
}
```

For each row,draw columns
each column object, step x co-ordinate by 60, y co-ordinate by row * 57; This way per row you are painting, x will increment pre column, y will remain same for a row.

Answer (score 0):

You could move `ctx.fillStyle` outside of the loops and take a nested loop with just a count for each element/rectangle and take this value with a factor for the position for drawing.

You want 5 lines of dots, starting with one dot in the first line until you reach 5 dotes in the last line.

For this approach, you could take two nested loops, the outer for the lines/y-values and the inner for the columns/x-values.

For getting the right position, you could apply a factor and the given offset.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rw = 50,
    rh = 50,
    x = 10,
    y = 10,
    i, j;

ctx.fillStyle = "orange";

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(x + i * 60, y + j * 57, rw, rh);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```